# SQL Group attendance list by user and time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have list of users on site

| User | In | Out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | 31.10.2023 04:20 |  |
| User 1 |  | 31.10.2023 05:20 |
| User 1 | 31.10.2023 05:25 |  |
| User 2 | 31.10.2023 02:20 |  |
| User 3 | 31.10.2023 03:00 |  |
| User 3 |  | 31.10.2023 05:20 |
| User 3 |  | 31.10.2023 05:21 |

I want to get the result list with users who are on Site

| User | In |
| --- | --- |
| User 1 | 31.10.2023 05:25 |
| User 2 | 31.10.2023 02:20 |

Please help with SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by each user and select only those having a higher IN than OUT which means they are still in.

```
select user_name, max(in_time)
from your_table
group by user_name
having max(in_time) > max(out_time)
```

Comment: Juergen - perfect, thanks, I knew that it will simple, but... thx a mil